# VBA - On error Inside a For Loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have an `OnError` method inside the for loop. I am getting an error when the OnError is used for the second time.

This is my code,

```
For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1
  Sheets(TabName2).Activate
  CombinedKeyVal = Range(CombinedKeyColLet & i).Value

  On Error GoTo Jumpdelete

  Present = WorksheetFunction.Match(CombinedKeyVal, Sheets(TabName1).Columns(6), 0)
  If Present <> "" Then
    GoTo Jumpdontdelete
  End If

Jumpdelete:
  Sheets(TabName2).Activate
  Rows(i & ":" & i).Delete

Jumpdontdelete:

Next
```

How do I handle this for `n` number of times. Please kindly share your thoughts.

Comment: You are supposed to use `resume` to return from your error handler. E.g. `resume Jumpdontdelete`.

Comment: What's the error you're seeing?

Comment: saying match not found ! for the line present=application*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this *specific* case, `Dim Present As Variant` and use `Application.Match` instead of `WorksheetFunction.Match`. The `Application.Match` function *returns* an error without raising it (this is why you need to assign as a `Variant` type):

```
Dim Present As Variant
For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1
    CombinedKeyVal = Sheets(TabName2).Range(CombinedKeyColLet & i).Value
    Present = Application.Match(CombinedKeyVal, Sheets(TabName1).Columns(6), 0)
    If IsError(Present) Then
        Sheets(TabName2).Rows(i & ":" & i).Delete
    End If
Next
```

This avoids the spaghettification of your code with tons of `GoTo` and `Resume` statements which are tricky to follow & troubleshoot.

Also I [cleaned up your code a little bit to avoid relying on `Activate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros).

Comment: *That* is the answer. **Don't use errors for flow control**, and of course *avoid GOTO jumps* and spaghetti logic.